# Python: calling a child function using a string

Tags: python, string, methods, parent-child

Does anyone know how to call a child function that belongs to a parent function using the dot operator, but where the child function's name is stored in a string variable.

```
def parent_function():
   # do something
   def child_function():
      # do something else
```

Now imagine I have a string called 'child_function'. Is there a way to do this:

```
method_name = 'child_function'
parent_function.method_name()
```

I understand that method_name is a string and so it is not callable. The syntax above is clearly wrong, but I wanted to know if there was a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: That's just not a correct design.  You can set up a dict to do the mapping: `mapping = {'child_function': child_function, 'other_function': other_function}`.  That way, it's easy to check for mistakes.

Comment: How do you call it even when it's not a string? `child_function` is local to `parent_function`. You cannot access it from outside.

Comment: You will have to set up some logic, the parent will have to take in a parameter, where every value will run a separate child function and return a value using if..else on that parameter.

Comment: The big question is "Why do you want to do this?" What problem are you trying to solve? This is clearly an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm going to agree with everyone else.  Don't do this.  What actual problem are you trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following case:

```
def parent_function():
  a = 1
```

Can you access `a` from the global scope? No, because it is a local variable. It is only existent while `parent_function` runs, and forgotten after.

Now, in python, a function is stored in a variable just like any other value. `child_function` is a local variable just like `a`. Thus, it is in principle not possible to access it from outside `parent_function`.

Edit: unless you make it available to the outside somehow, e.g. by returning it. But then, still the name `child_function` is internal to `parent_function`.

Edit 2: You can get functions given by name (as string) by using the `locals()` and `globals()` dictionaries.

```
def my_function():
    print "my function!"

func_name = "my_function"
f = globals()[func_name]
f()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in comments there will need to be a little more setup to actually call an inner function, such as a parameter like this:

```
def parent_function(should_call=False):
   # do something
   def child_function():
      print("I'm the child")
   if should_call:
       child_function()
```

That being said, and to answer your specific question, you *technically* can call the inner function directly. I should note this is bad and you should **not** be doing this. You can access the inner function via the outer function's code object

```
exec(parent_function.__code__.co_consts[1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation - learnt about the use of __code__.co_consts[1].

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to many comments, you can actually access inner functions even if the outer function is not in the system memory anymore. This technique in python is called closure.
To know more about closure, [visit Programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure)

Coming to your requirement, you need to call the nested method outside the nesting function.

What are we leveraging?

1. Closure technique of python
2. `locals()` method which returns all the local properties and methods inside an enclosing method.
3. `lambda x: x`, A anonymous (Lambda) function

```py
def parent_function():
    # do something

    def child_function():
        # do something else
        print("child_function got invoked")

    return {i: j for i, j in locals().items() if type(j) == type(lambda x: x)}
    # locals() returns all the properties and nested methods inside an enclosing method.
    # We are filtering out only the methods / funtions and not properties / variables

parent_function()["child_function"]()
```

The below is the output.

```py
>>> child_function got invoked
```

#### Better Solution:

Instead of using nested methods, leverage the concept of classes provided by Python.
Enclose the nested functions as methods inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you include `global child_function` in `parent_function`, then once you run `parent_function`, you can call `child_function` in the main program. It's not a very clean way of defining functions, though. If you want a function defined in the main program, then you should define it in the main program.